# libtorch throws c10::error after build on Windows 10 (VS2019)

Tags: windows, pytorch, visual-studio-2019, libtorch

I've tried to build libtorch on Windows 10 using VS 2019 without CUDA and Python. Independent if I compile it with or without MKL, a simple test program crashes directly after start. After building the debug version, libtorch throws a `c10:error` in a function called `torchCheckFail`.

The function seems to complain about `ATen/core/jit_type.h`.

The problem is part of torch_cpu.dll. The problem disappears when I'm using the precompiled binaries for Windows.

Here's the function:

```
void torchCheckFail(
    const char* func,
    const char* file,
    uint32_t line,
    const std::string& msg) {
  throw ::c10::Error({func, file, line}, msg);
}
```

And here's the call stack:

[image: Call Stack]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same exact error with the same environment.

A solution that worked for me was to take a release version of pytorch and not a non-release one (i.e. a release version + some commits).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have provided a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76611345/8437317). Please take a look at it for more information.

**TL/DR:** try to use `cmake + Ninja + x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019` to build libtoch on windows 10, which maybe helps. The idea comes from [this issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/24186#issuecomment-522478307).